# How do I run Angry Birds?

Tags: launcher, games, chromium

I see that there is an HTML version of Angry Birds. How do I use it? I'd also like to have the icon on my launcher so I can run it as it's own application.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

1. In `chromium-browser` go to  [Angry Birds](http://chrome.angrybirds.com/)
2. Click on the wrench icon and select `Tools` → `Create Application Shortcuts...`

   [image]
3. Select `Desktop` to create a shortcut on your desktop

   [image]
4. Move it to `.local/share/applications/`

   *(Optional) Download an icon for Angry Birds and replace the original icon*

   [image]
5. Drag the icon onto the launcher

   [image]
6. Win

   [image]

Comment: worthy of a +1 :)

Comment: where can I get the icons from?

Comment: I usually get the icons from Google images icons.See [Angry Birds](http://www.google.ps/search?q=angry+birds&hl=en&biw=1280&bih=714&tbm=isch&prmd=ivnsu&source=lnt&tbs=isz:i&sa=X&ei=y1METv_fIo2BhQfowuCvDQ&ved=0CAwQpwUoAw)

Answer (score 5):

It's just a webpage. Firefox 4.0.1 (what should ship in Ubuntu 11.04) plays it fine, albeit a little bit slower.

[Play the BETA version. (Only the 63 levels of stage 1 and a few bonus levels.)](http://chrome.angrybirds.com/)

To make an ad-hoc launcher, when using Firefox, merely drag the favicon in the address bar to your desktop.

Answer (score 0):

http://chrome.angrybirds.com/.

Runs in all web browser supporting html5 I guess..my bad ..for saying it a chrome addon coz I heard the same first.

But it can be installed in chromium/chrome as a plugin as well.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/aknpkdffaafgjchaibgeefbgmgeghloj?hl=en-US

Ok copied this from Gmail.desktop unity launcher but works

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Angry Birds
Exec=/usr/bin/chromium-browser --app=http://chrome.angrybirds.com
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Icon=
Categories=Games;
StartupNotify=true
```

Comment: It's just a webpage. It doesn't require Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

About the icon of the launcher you should go , using chrome, to the tools icon (a wrench on the right side) then to the "tools" submenu and the "create application shortcut" option after that.

Afterwards you can just drag ' n ' drop the icon in the launcher, getting what you want.

A shortcut of that style can be made using firefox as well if i recall correctly - performance is a little problematic on my firefox though

*by the way, what do you mean "how do i use it?" ?