# How to properly pin Chrome/ium apps in their own "application" in Unity?

Tags: unity, google-chrome, chromium, pinning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I put a web application on the Launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31427/how-do-i-put-a-web-application-on-the-launcher)

What I mean is, how can I pin a Chrome/ium application and keep it to itself? I want to click on the application and have it run in its own pin... Its hard to describe. What happens now is, when I click on an app, it runs in either an application that is already open or in the Chrome/ium that is already open. It only stays to itself if you only have that one application open.

If that isn't clear enough, I'll edit this post with some screenshots.

I'm running 11.04 with a Developers build of Chrome.

Comment: I think screen shots would be very useful!

Comment: I think what he's saying is he'd like to run it like the [Angry Birds one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/42239/how-do-i-run-angry-birds)

Comment: This doesn't work right due to a bug in BAMF, as long as you set it up as the question I just duped it in it should be fine once BAMF is fixed.

Comment: Yeah, its the bug where "Unity gets confused." If its supposed to be fixed by that, then this question should be closed.