# Can I create a Unity URL launcher for the Applications Lens?

Tags: unity, lenses

Can I create an application launcher that is a URL? I would like to modify the application screen of my Ubuntu Dash to include icons that open links.

Comment: Yes. Answer is in this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/42239/how-do-i-run-angry-birds replace angry birds URL and image for your URL and image.

Comment: @Rinzwind That should probably go in an answer below.

Comment: No, this should be closed as a dupe ;)

Comment: No... that question is a specific instance of this question. If anything 42239 should be the dupe. Does anyone know if Firefox has a similar feature to "Create Launcher"? I think a GUI answer to this would be best...

Comment: Not aware of that in FF, the drag favicon in FF will create a .desktop but not of the kind that can be added to the launcher. The launcher needs Type=Application, Exec=command url, while the DnD .desktop is Type=Link, Url=whatever. While Users can create their own launcher url launchers quite easily off a simple template, haven't seen a gui app to do so & this may be better suited for quicklists anyway